# How to isolate the largest fragment of string without special characters?

Tags: php

What would be the best approach to isolate the largest fragment of a string without special characters?

For example:

```
$string = '!1@22#33333$444';
```

The output I would be looking for is "33333".

Comment: Do you have some code that you've tried but can't get working?

Comment: @cOle2 Thanks for your reply! Someone over on Reddit pointed me in the direction of using preg_match & preg_match_all, which is a much simpler solution for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on Reddit was kind enough to point me in the direction of preg_match & preg_match_all for a solution:

```
<?php
$newstring = 'Miedito o Qué? (feat. KAROL G)@';

if(preg_match('/[^a-z_\-0-9().&$!:\s]/i', $newstring))
{
  echo "not clean<br>";
  if(preg_match_all('/[a-z_\-0-9().&$!:\s]+/i', $newstring, $matches))
  {
    print_r($matches);
  } 
}
else
{
  echo "clean<br>";
}
?>
```